# Ignore/Remove all but 1 Dynamic field SOLR

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a copy field in schema.xml as

```
<copyField source="attr_*" dest="defaultSearch" />
```

but I want to copy all fields from source `attr_* (i.e. attr_A*, attr_B*, ... attr_Z*)` but I do NOT want to copy `attr_K*` 
from source to destination.
There are also 10 other different fields having `dest="defaultSearch"`

I am using solr 6-5.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that will require you to spell out all the names you _do want_ to copy.

Comment: if these fields are really called the way you mention, most likely you should list them all, as @MatsLindh said